# How to average daily precipitation values into weekly sum in R

Tags: raster, r, aggregate

I would like to sum the daily precipitation values into a weekly format such that the raster layers names would be the first day of the weekly sum.

```
> print(prec_brick_ES)
class      : RasterBrick 
dimensions : 30, 52, 1560, 366  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
resolution : 0.25, 0.25  (x, y)
extent     : -9.5, 3.5, 36, 43.5  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
crs        : +proj=longlat +datum=WGS84 +no_defs 
source     : memory
names      :   X2020.01.01,   X2020.01.02,   X2020.01.03,   X2020.01.04,   X2020.01.05,   X2020.01.06,   X2020.01.07,   X2020.01.08,   X2020.01.09,   X2020.01.10,   X2020.01.11,   X2020.01.12,   X2020.01.13,   X2020.01.14,   X2020.01.15, ... 
min values :  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13,  1.665335e-13, ... 
max values :     0.4501366,     1.6013724,     6.3910065,     3.6800153,     1.0156338,     1.0018753,     0.5399953,     1.6643792,     5.3558488,    17.3246708,     8.5622196,     7.0873837,    20.1449661,    13.9195910,    26.3084259, ... 
time       : 2020-01-01, 2020-12-31 (min, max)
```

Comment: I think you are asking two different questions here, 1) how to sum raster layers and, 2) how to extract the name of the first daily raster and use it as a name to your weekly raster (please correct me if I'm wrong). The best way to receive an answer is if you post 1 question per post, this means that, you should separate your initial question into 2. Regarding how to sum multiple rasters using the terra package have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75879431/merging-multiple-spatrasters-by-sum-in-r-package-terra).